# Error deleting row from table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a very strange error that happens when I try to delete a row from my table. The error I get is:

`Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

I've read this is usually an error when someone doesn't remove the object from their data source before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. However, I'm doing this... Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         /* Remove from DB */
        [dbHandler deleteRow:indexPath];
        /* Removing row from data source */
        [[self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        /* Remove row from table - It fails on this line... */
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
     }
}
```

When I step through this in a debugger, it certainly deletes that object from the datasource. Is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: Are you sure your dbHandler doesn't update your listData, and vice versa?

Comment: quite sure.. it only does a direct db query to delete the resulting row in the db. I also stepped through this in the debugger. It successfully removes the row from the datasource right before deleteRowsAtIndexPaths is called and the count of listData is as expected.

Comment: Check what does your numberOfRowsInSection method returns just before the [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths] method call. Personally, I forget to update a DataSource data structures after updating database quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I was adding an extra row when to my table when there were more rows to load than were already rendered on the screen.  Similar to how the Mail app does the "Load more" feature...  I wasn't taking into account this extra cell when I deleted them.